# Prove that $x_n \rightarrow x \iff x_{2n},\ x_{2n+1}$ and $x_{3n}$ also converges to $x$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence in $X$ and $x\in X$. Then $$\lim \limits _{n\to \infty} x_n = x \iff \lim \limits _{n\to \infty} x_{2n}=\lim \limits _{n\to \infty} x_{2n+1}=\lim \limits _{n\to \infty} x_{3n}=x$$

The exercise doesn't especify the metric that is being used, is this even necessary?

Well, $\Rightarrow$ is trivial.

On $\Leftarrow$ I thought: I wan't to prove that given $\epsilon$ then $\exists N; n\geq N \rightarrow d(x_n,x)<\epsilon$. But, I know that there is some $N$ like that for even index or odd index, hence if I take the greatest $N$ of each case I'll have a natural that the statment holds for all $n$.

But it's weird because I didn't used the fact that $x_{3n}\rightarrow x$ (of course, if my ideia is right than this converges to $x$)

I'd be grateful if you help me!
(and i'm sorry if its duplicated)

Comment: You don't need the condition $x_{3n} \to x$, for exactly the reason you stated. I think the question might have been botched a little, and was meant to ask whether $x_n$ converges if and only if $x_{2n}$, $x_{2n+1}$, and $x_{3n}$ converge, because then you would need $x_{3n}$ to show that the even and odd subsequence limits are equal.

Comment: Your idea is correct. $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n = x$ is also equivalent to $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{2n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}x_{2n + 1} = x$.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct and based on that you can write a formal proof without using the sub sequence $\{ x_{3n}\}$ because it is not really needed for the convergence of your sequence.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but I don't think this is correct. The claim you seem to be making is: Provided the subsequences of odd indexed elements and even indexed elements converge, then the sequence converges. But it's clearly not true -- consider the sequence $(0,1,0,1,0,1,\ldots)$

Comment: @dbx The answer is right, because the even and odd subsequences are assumed to converge **to the same limit**.

Comment: oh yes of course, thanks. That makes this problem much less interesting.

Comment: @dbx i'm sorry then! ahahaahahhau